# Searching for the name of a rotary switch/push button switch combination

Tags: switches, rotary, push-pull

I'm looking for a switch that combines a rotary switch and a push button switch. The only one I could find is the "Würth Elektronik WS-RPTL 481RV12172100" which is not exactly what I was hoping to find.

I am really surprised not to find more of this kind of switches, as for instance modern microwave ovens seem to use them a lot (like the Samsung MC32F604TCT, I think).

Am I only missing the correct name for this kind of switch or are they really that rare?

Comment: Probably rotary encoder push button.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic inn this forum.  See Help->Tour>Don't ask about...Shopping or buying recommendations

Comment: It's not a buying recommendation. I'm just asking for a name or hint here.

Comment: EE.SE is for questions about stuff like: 1) 
    a specific electronics design problem
    2) the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
    3) a communication scheme
    4) the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications and is not about and it is not about …
    "a shopping or buying recommendation" I'm not trying to discourage you from posting questions, but please post them withing the guidelines. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Combined rotary switches with push-activation combinations have never been commodity items that you could buy separately unless you were a major customer. They are virtually always "OEM" components which are custom-made for a specific mass-market product. In previous eras, you could buy "replacement" parts if you found a particular switch you liked in a consumer product, etc.  But in the modern era, we don't believe in component-level repair, so you can't even buy them as "replacement/repair" parts any more.

In virtually ALL modern products the combined rotary/push function is implemented as a ROTARY ENCODER with a push-switch function built-in.  There are many different versions of this available. But they assume that you are using a micro-controller and the switch simply sends "step-clockwise" or "step-anti-clockwise" pulses to the micro-controller.